# Java help, Null Values

Tags: java, object, null

I was wondering why this code is not printing null and prints 0 instead. Could anyone explain when null default values are assigned and when null is assigned to a data field?

```
public class Circle {
  private double radius;

  public Circle(double radius) {
    radius = radius;
 }

  public static void main(String[] args){
      Circle circle = new Circle(4);
      System.out.println("radius: "+ circle.radius);
   }
 }
```

Comment: It's a `double` primitive type, and it's a class member variable, so it's initialized to zero.  If it was a `Double` Object and a class member variable, it would be initialized with null.

Comment: Oh so primitive data types get assigned to null default data types but null gets assigned to objects

Comment: It's not possible for a primitive type to be null, only Object references can be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Primitives vs. References**

**primitive types** are the basic types of data
byte, short, int, long, float, double, boolean, char
primitive variables store primitive values

**reference types** are any instantiable class as well as arrays
String, Scanner, Random, Die, int[], String[], etc.
reference variables store addresses

only reference types are deafult initialized with NULL.

Reference: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~bahls/cs302/PrimitiveVsReference.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the differences between *primitive types* and *reference types*.

One of the differences between them is that primitive type variables cannot be set to null while reference type objects can. In other words, **primitive types must have a value.**

And `double` is a primitive type! So that's why it will never be null.

"But I *really* want it to be null, though!" you shouted. The workaround for this is to use `Double` instead of `double`. Why? If you haven't guessed already, `Double` is actually a reference type!